# Defining a property on a declared function with a generic argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm adding typescript declarations to my JavaScript config loader [milieu](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/Milieu).

The library exports a function named milieu which is generic over a type Config. The function returns an instance of Milieu, a type which is a merger of Config and MilieuConstructor (This is because in the JS implementation the Milieu class contructor copies each config value into the instance).

All of this works fine when using the exported function, but we run into a problem. The milieu function also has a property Milieu which has the Milieu contructor as it's value. I cannot figure out how to add this contructor to the exported function without creating a collision with the milieu namespace.

```js
declare namespace milieu {

  export interface Opts {
    argv?: string
    env?: { [s: string]: string }
    platform?: string
    cwd?: string
    unsetEnvValues?: boolean
    parseValues?: boolean
  }

  export class MilieuConstructor<Config> {
    constructor (applicationName: string, defaults: Config, opts?: Opts)
  }

  export type Milieu<Config> = Config & MilieuConstructor<Config>
}

declare function milieu<Config>(applicationName: string, defaults: Config, opts?: milieu.Opts): milieu.Milieu<Config>

export = milieu
```

I would like the following code to be valid using my typings:

```
import milieu from 'milieu'

interface MyConfig {
  port: number
}

// This one currently works
const config1 = milieu<MyConfig>('myApplication', {
  port: 8000
});

// This one does not as milieu.Milieu does not exist as a value
const config2 = new milieu.Milieu<MyConfig>('myApplication', {
  port: 8000
});
```

Here is a [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20milieu%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20export%20interface%20Opts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20argv?:%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20env?:%20%7B%20[s:%20string]:%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20platform?:%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cwd?:%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20unsetEnvValues?:%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%20%20parseValues?:%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20export%20class%20MilieuConstructor%3CConfig%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20(applicationName:%20string,%20defaults:%20Config,%20opts?:%20Opts)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20export%20type%20Milieu%3CConfig%3E%20=%20Config%20&%20MilieuConstructor%3CConfig%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20milieu%3CConfig%3E(applicationName:%20string,%20defaults:%20Config,%20opts?:%20milieu.Opts):%20milieu.Milieu%3CConfig%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20=%20milieu%0D%0A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `Milieu` value as well as the type. It will have to be a constructor signature that returns a `Milieu<Config>`

```
declare namespace milieu {

    export interface Opts {
      argv?: string
      env?: { [s: string]: string }
      platform?: string
      cwd?: string
      unsetEnvValues?: boolean
      parseValues?: boolean
    }

    export class MilieuConstructor<Config> {
      constructor (applicationName: string, defaults: Config, opts?: Opts)
    }

    export type Milieu<Config> = Config & MilieuConstructor<Config>
    export const Milieu: new <Config>(applicationName: string, defaults: Config, opts?: Opts) => Milieu<Config>
  }

  declare function milieu<Config>(applicationName: string, defaults: Config, opts?: milieu.Opts): milieu.Milieu<Config>

  export = milieu
```

Comment: Very very cool. I didn't know you could have a const with a type starting with new like this. Thanks very much. You've made my day.